# Lagrangian and equations of motion on a pseudospherical surface

Tags: classical-mechanics

A particle of mass m oscillates up and down on a smooth surface of revolution parameterized as:

$$(x= a  \sin  \phi \cos t, y= a \sin  \phi  \sin t,z= a(\cos  \phi+ \log \tan  \phi/2 )\;) $$

The  $z$-axis is vertical up. $t$ is polar angle, $\phi$ is angle of tangent to z-axis.

A 3d spiral motion on this pseudospherical horn ensues without friction under the action of gravity. The trajectories look somewhat like this when viewed along $z$ axis:

[image: Precession]

Depending on the kinetic energy imparted at start  other orbits can be seen.

Please  help find the Lagrangian of the system and its time period of oscillation. Comments for clarification/ solution appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  And are you *sure* this is your equation?  As $t \to \infty$, then $z \to \infty$.  What do you mean "up and down"?

Comment: I tried to a pull a  parabolic cylinder ( posted a while ago)  into rotational symmetric form  but wondering what would be an easy way to start. Later on with EL equns etc. may be no problem, but entering into it is the problem..

Comment: @  David G Stork: The equation is standard for its meridian. Even if depth is infinite a spiral need not go to the deepest point. I saw a shallow one play out  in Carnegie Science Center Pittsburgh  and another deeper one in India. Quite amusing. Almost sure we can handle its dynamic formulation.

Comment: @ David G Stork: Another parametrization that is meridian based. The initial downward direction of spiral path should not be along meridian to let it later return along a helical path upwards.

Comment: I think you should plot this function.  It would clarify a *lot*.

Comment: The time function is unknown.

Comment: "Time function is unknown."  What does that even *mean*??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116406/discussion-between-narasimham-and-david-g-stork).

Comment: @ David G Stork: What  function do you refer to for plotting?

Comment: @ David G Stork: The top view of orbits seen resembles a bit like in the  new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$$
p = (x,y,z)=\left(a \sin (\phi (\tau )) \cos (t(\tau )),a \sin (\phi (\tau )) \sin (t(\tau )),a \left(\cos (\phi (\tau
   ))+\ln \left(\tan \left(\frac{\phi (\tau )}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)
$$

we have

$$
v = \dot p = \left(a \left(\phi '(\tau ) \cos (\phi (\tau )) \cos (t(\tau ))-\sin (\phi (\tau )) t'(\tau ) \sin (t(\tau
   ))\right),a \left(\phi '(\tau ) \cos (\phi (\tau )) \sin (t(\tau ))+\sin (\phi (\tau )) t'(\tau ) \cos (t(\tau
   ))\right),a \phi '(\tau ) \cos (\phi (\tau )) \cot (\phi (\tau ))\right)
$$

so the Lagrangian reads

$$
L = \frac 12 m v\cdot v - m g z(\phi(\tau)) = \frac{1}{2} a m \left(a \phi '(\tau )^2 \cot ^2(\phi (\tau ))+a \sin ^2(\phi (\tau )) t'(\tau )^2-2 g \left(\cos
   (\phi (\tau ))+\ln \left(\tan \left(\frac{\phi (\tau )}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)
$$

the movement equations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \phi ''(\tau )& = & \sin (\phi (\tau )) \left(\sin (\phi (\tau )) \tan (\phi (\tau )) t'(\tau
   )^2-\frac{g}{a}\right)+\phi '(\tau )^2 \csc (\phi (\tau )) \sec (\phi (\tau )) \\
 t''(\tau )& = & -2 \phi '(\tau ) \cot (\phi (\tau )) t'(\tau ) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving those DEs for $a = 1, m = 1, g = 10, \phi(0) = 0.5, t(0) = 0.5, \dot\phi(0) = 1,\dot t(0)= 2$ we obtain the corresponding orbit in blue, shown in the attached plot

[image]

Follows the orbit projected into the $XY$ plane

[image]

Follows the plot for $z$ (black), $t(\tau)/10$ (red), and $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (blue)

[image]

Comment: So well formed !  I saw a particle ( a small steel ball was used ) that goes so deep in and comes back to its original height after a few rotations in the well, and all that has been fully formulated here ..Can we also see $ r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z $ plots for a couple of periods?

Comment: I wish to compare the calculated period with $ 2 \pi \sqrt {a/g}.$

Comment: Please. See plot attached.

Comment: Please include $z(\tau), t(\tau)$ along with $r(\tau)$ on same axes. The precession and its rate are also  quite  interesting.Wonder if there is a law/phenomenon  about it.

Comment: Thanks for the (r,t,z) plots. Can we address three related questions: 1) You  used Euler-Lagrange equations on Lagrangian with independent variables $ ϕ(\tau), ϕ′(τ) \text { and }  t(τ),t′(τ)$ separately... to obtain the two coupled  DEs, right? 2) The particle periodically moves on the *fixed (same) closed path* shown in which the z seems proportionate to r okay? 3) Is there a way to find time period analytically?